# Nsarray count +1 from current item & loop

Tags: cocoa, for-loop, count, nsarray, avplayer

I am writing a audio player App using AVAudio Player to play mp3's from the NSDocs Dir loading them with ALAssetsLibrary subclass & AVURLAsset When I select a mp3 from the tableview it will push to a player & play but Im struggling with the skip & previous buttons
I can skip to the last track with the below code, although I'm unsure if this is correct approach sending one AVURLAsset to play rather than a queue array.

[Im using apple sample project AVPlayerDemo as the foundation of the ALAssetsLibrary subclass](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVPlayerDemo/Introduction/Intro.html)

```
- (IBAction)nextButtonTapped:(id)sender {



NSArray *sourceitems = [[finalSources objectAtIndex:_selectedPath.section] items];


[sourceitems enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    id next = nil;
     next = [next objectAtIndex:_selectedPath.row];
    if (idx + 1 < sourceitems.count) {
        next = [sourceitems objectAtIndex:idx + 1];
        AssetBrowserItem *item = next;
        AVURLAsset *asset = (AVURLAsset*)item.asset;
        [self setURL:asset.URL];
        NSLog(@"next %@", next);

      //here it continues to the last object and plays, 
     //but i just want to skip one track and play, then click again and move 
     //to the next one

    }

  }];
}

- (void)setURL:(NSURL*)URL
{
if (mURL != URL)
{
    mURL = [URL copy];

    /*
     Create an asset for inspection of a resource referenced by a given URL.
     Load the values for the asset keys "tracks", "playable".
     */
    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:mURL options:nil];

    NSArray *requestedKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:kTracksKey, kPlayableKey, nil];

    /* Tells the asset to load the values of any of the specified keys that are not already loaded. */
    [asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:requestedKeys completionHandler:
     ^{
         dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                        ^{
                            /* IMPORTANT: Must dispatch to main queue in order to operate on the AVPlayer and AVPlayerItem. */
                            [self prepareToPlayAsset:asset withKeys:requestedKeys];
                            [self syncLabels:mURL];
                        });
     }];
}
```

}

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance Gav.

Comment: Need a bit more of your source to work things out but your for() statement should read 1 < finalSources.count not <=, also not sure what you're checking for in the loop. Also your assetbrowseritem refers to objectAtIndex:+1, this should be n+1 or row+1 or whatever. I'd suggest posting some more if your code and commenting your intentions well.

Comment: Sorry that was very vague, I edited and updated the question

Comment: First off I'd forget the enumerateUsingBlock call and just index straight into sourceItems. You are enumerating through all the objects in your array and ending up at the last one. so leave in the code from if (idx + 1 < sourceitems.count) { to } but lose the [sourceitems enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^ etc etc. Your lines id next = nil;
     next = [next objectAtIndex:_selectedPath.row]; this effectively equates to next = [nil objectAtIndex:_selectedPath.row]; which equals nil...

Comment: Ok thanks good points i'll give them a go, thanks again for replying.